# A forward converter or flyback converter without voltage spikes?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, flyback, damping-factor, feedforward

I was thinking of a way to avoid voltage spikes in a flyback converter and I decided to redirect voltage spikes back to the battery, hence dampening the voltage spikes. Will this method work efficiently or am I way off?[image: sketch of the circuit diagram]

Comment: Try simulating it - it's a modern craze that is taking hold amongst EEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand how a transformer works. Voltage on one winding gets reflected on the other windings based on their turns ratio.

You also have to understand how a flyback converter works, it flows current though an transformer until a certain current limit, and then it shuts down the switch, so the voltage rises in the opposite polarity.

Because you now redirect the voltage spikes, the voltage during a switch off will be 0V (assuming ideal diodes) on the transformer, so the secondary side also sees 0V, and no energy gets transferred.

This means you cannot limit the voltage spikes on a flyback preventing it from working (a small capacitor might be needed to deal with leakage inductance)

Your way of connecting inductor L4 at the secondary side makes the problem worse, the voltage needs to bounce up to an higher voltage to demagnetize the coil.

You would need to look into different topologies, which do not depend on energy flying back in the transformer. An example of the 2 step forward with 2 switching transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQhytU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With this 2 step design, both transistors only see a voltage spike up to the voltage rail + a diode drop

Comment: I don't think you looked at my circuit, the same effect of the spike being the same as the voltage rail still applies on my circuit

Comment: Read the third paragraph. Your solutions prevents the voltage from rising in the t<discharge> state of the flyback operation. This means no energy can be transferred to the secondary side

Comment: You do know forward converters that use a tertiary winding work similar to my circuit, when Q1 is switched on, current flows through the primary winding as it will be induced in the secondary winding L3, the tertiary winding L2 is there to avoid spikes but there definitely will be a transfer of energy

Comment: Single Switch Forward Converters transfer away from the secondary winding when the transistor is on. More current drawn means the current in the primary increases faster. Forward converters see a peak of vin  *2 in the main switching transistor. Even if we change the topology of your circuit to a Single Switch Forward Converter, the extra diode D1 you added prevents the voltage on the transformer from increasing, which in turn means the core demagnetized very slowly and can only be run at very low duty cycles. You need the voltage on the transformer to be high to get it to demagnetize fast.

Comment: @BleedingEdgeLab what Ferrybig is telling you is that a flyback circuit **MUST** allow the flyback voltage to be seen at the primary else the circuit doesn't work; the energy that you want to transfer to the secondary gets dissipated in the clamp you are trying to use. This cannot be allowed to happen.

Comment: @Ferrybig Thank you for your input, I still think I need a different response but I appreciate the effort and I will actually look into what you are saying, maybe I am just blinded by something. Thank you

Comment: @BleedingEdgeLab Try playing around in a electrical simulator to see how the circuits react, instead of reading theory, you might learn faster than way. For example https://tinyurl.com/yb6gzdwm (note that this simulator is not the most accurate, but in most cases, it is good enough)